# Changing XSLT generation in MapForce

Tags: altova, map-force

I have a strange problem. I am generating an XSD to XSD mapping in MapForce and it is valid and producing output. However when the XSLT is utilized by our DataPower folks, they are saying the namespace prefixes in the XSLT are causing the code to not find the nodes in the incoming message.

For example in the XSLT, the select is:

```
<xsl:for-each select="ns0:costOrderHeaderLookupResponse/return/ns1:Order">
```

In the incoming message, the namespace prefix is as below:

```
*snip*
<return>
<ns2:Order BillToID="300850001000" DocumentType="0001"....*snip*>
```

However MapForce is generating the output just fine with no errors even with the namespace prefix difference.

The DataPower folks are requesting that instead of the namespace prefix I customize MapForce to output the nodes like this:

```
/*[local-name()='Order']
```

I read the MapForce documentation and googled for awhile but I am not finding a way to customize XSLT output like this. It is possible for C/Java/etc but I am not finding any help on changing how the XSLT is generated.

Answer (score 0):

Create a filter in MapForce and use a boolean function (like `core:logical functions:equal`) to check to see if the `local-name` of the node in the `select` (`costOrderHeaderLookupResponse/return/Order`) has a local-name equal to a constant string with value `Order`.  The function to check for the  local-name should be in the `xslt:xpath functions` library as `local-name`.

The filter should replace your connection from the Orders node to whatever node it is mapped to in the second XSD.

To see how filters work (assuming you aren't already using one to get your select) view http://manual.altova.com/Mapforce/mapforcebasic/index.html?mfffilteringdata.htm

Comment: If you need further help, or I am totally off, please comment here, as I do not have enough rep to comment at the moment.  I would ask that you provide information on how the domain XSD is connected to the range XSD (is there a filter there already?).